# Application (Qt Creator) is unresponsive on launch, even after reinstalling

Tags: 14.04, qt, qt-creator

When I try to open **Qt Creator**, it loads fine but after a couple of seconds, the application window becomes unresponsive and turns gray. I can move the window around, but cannot interact with it. It remains like this indefinitely.

The same thing happens if I try to open a Qt project file with Qt Creator.

And if I try to close the window, I get a dialog box that reads:

```
This Window is not responding
Do you want to force the application to exit, or wait for it to respond?
```

This happened all of a sudden, while I was working on a Qt Creator project. I don't remember making any change to the Qt Creator installation either.

Among a few things that I have already tried are:

1. Restart my machine
2. Uninstall and reinstall Qt Creator (using Ubuntu Software Centre)

What else should I try to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using the ubuntu sdk?

Comment: I don't know what that is, so not as far as I am aware...

Comment: Try starting it in a terminal like qtcreator

Comment: If I run it from a terminal, I get the same behaviour.

Comment: Did you get errors? If so what where they?

Comment: There were no error messages when I started the application, it just froze. The only message I received was the dialog box, as mentioned above.

Comment: What did the crash log say?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually managed to solve this by removing the directory `QtProject` and the file `QtProject.conf` from the directory `~/.config`. After doing this and restarting QtCreator, it seems to now run as expected. However, I don't understand the real reason behind why this worked.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to remove the file ./config/QtProject/QtCreator.ini.lock
It seems that QtCreator marks a file as 'locked' by writng this file.
If it dies while this is still present and fails to delete it, QtCreator believes the lock is still held when it tries to restart.